# Could not open a connection to your authentication agent

Tags: osx, ssh-agent

I am using a mac.

and I am trying to add the key to the agent.

```
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:XSLT vinay$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 49170
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:XSLT vinay$ ssh-agent
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/var/folders/x2/pb3kl7dn1cl02pr8llz947740000gn/T//ssh-wLSfLyFN3W27/agent.49177; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=49178; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 49178;
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:XSLT vinay$ sudo ssh-add xx.xxx 
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:XSLT vinay$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually Macs already run ssh-agent by default.

```
$ps ax | grep ssh-agent
648   ??  S      0:00.09 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
```

ssh-add should be run also as your user, and not as root, as you want to add the password to your RSA private key. Hence also the error, as root has no associated ssh-agent running.

You just really need to run:

```
ssh-add
```

and enter the password.

You can also add the private key to your keychain permanently with the command. The password will be asked at the time you run the command.

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: If i don't use sudo, it won't run the command for me.

Comment: just run ssh-add with nothing else, it works for me. If not, please detail errors. If you are running with sudo, you are *running it with other user*; it should be run with your user.